# How to apply different content to a single property in style located in Resource Dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 textboxes which using **AddItemTextBoxStyle**:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtItemA" Style="{StaticResource AddItemTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>

<TextBox x:Name="txtItemB" Style="{StaticResource AddItemTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
```

Inside the **AddItemTextBoxStyle** (which is a style in **Resource Dictionary**), I have a tag property which sets the watermark text within the textbox:

```
<Style x:Key="AddItemTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Type here" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
               <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkTextStyle}" x:Name="WaterMarkLabel" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter.Property>
</Style>
```

By default, the watermark text is "Type here". However, if I want the watermark text to be different in the two textboxes, for example:

- Textbox txtItemA - "Type Item A here"
- Textbox txtItemB - "Type Item B here"

May I know how can I do this? Since the style is located in resource dictionary.

I try to search online but still unable to find a clue for it.

Comment: Are you looking for default watermark to be different, or you want a way to set it differently?

Comment: @Bolu Apologize for not being cleared about my question, was about to set a default watermark, then set two different watermark for two textboxes. The answer from Liero works! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtItemA" Style="{StaticResource AddItemTextBoxStyle}" Tag="Some wathermark" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtItemB" Style="{StaticResource AddItemTextBoxStyle}" Tag="Another watermarks" />
```

notice, that your style just sets default value of tag. Actual value is set in control instance and template binding takes the value from instance, not from style.

Comment: Gosh, that was embarrassingly easy! You taught me something new! Thanks ;)